# Filter array based on regex

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I have following array:

```
array = ['S2A_MSIL1C_20180213T041901_N0206_R090_T46QCH_20180213T075744.SAFE','S2B_MSIL1C_20180208T041929_N0206_R090_T46QCJ_20180208T075342.SAFE','S2A_MSIL1C_20180213T041901_N0206_R090_T46QCJ_20180213T075744.SAFE','S2B_MSIL1C_20180310T041559_N0206_R090_T46QDK_20180310T075716.SAFE']
```

I filter this array using this regex:

```
regex = new RegExp('(T46QCJ|s)','g');
```

and apply it on the array like

```
var filter = array.filter(e => regex.test(e));
```

The output is

```
["S2B_MSIL1C_20180208T041929_N0206_R090_T46QCJ_20180208T075342.SAFE"]
```

instead of the desired result

```
['S2B_MSIL1C_20180208T041929_N0206_R090_T46QCJ_20180208T075342.SAFE','S2A_MSIL1C_20180213T041901_N0206_R090_T46QCJ_20180213T075744.SAFE']
```

Why is the second match not inserted?

Comment: Get rid of the "g" flag. That's the problem. I don't know why but the "g" flag has some sort of mystique.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the dublicate question.

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/9c8ewd5b/2/. No mystique, it just advances the regex index upon a valid match.

Comment: For me its working perfectly fine with regex /(T46QCJ|s)/g

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew right I know what it does, but what I don't know is what makes it so unnecessarily popular :)

Comment: @binariedMe if you put that regex **literal** in the `.filter()` callback the code works because that regex is brand new on each call to the callback.

Comment: Oh, that's news to me. Great to know that. @Pointy Thanks